# Resize button in swift/xcode with Autolayout enabled

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have read in several other SO posts about this topic, and it's my understanding that to resize an object when AutoLayout is enabled, you can simply change the constant properties of their constraints in your code.

I have two buttons side by side, like this

[delete][ post ]

and they take up the entire width of the screen. I want to hide the delete button for certain views, and when that happens, stretch the post button to take up the entire width of the screen. In my code, I have:

```
self.postButtonLeadingConstraint.constant = self.deleteButtonLeadingConstraint.constant
self.deleteButton.hidden
```

My delete button hides just fine, but my post button stays exactly where it is at. What is it that I am doing wrong? Any input is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: If it matters, my buttons are constrained as follows:

Delete button leading constrained to leading edge of view

Post button leading constrained to trailing edge of delete button

Delete and post button set to equal each others' widths

both buttons have their tops and buttons constrained to the view they are in, but I don't see how those could be relevant.

Comment: What constraints have you added ? Can you post it

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
self.postButtonLeadingConstraint.constant -= self.deleteButton.frame.size.width
self.deleteButton.hidden = true
```

Comment: Not sure why, but this made my post button disappear entirely. Are you sure this isn't attaching it to the right edge of the screen?

Comment: This very nearly works! For some reason, my post button extends almost all the way to the edge of the screen, but theres a roughly 10 pixel gap remaining. I have no idea why this is happening, considering the combined buttons take up the entirely of the width of the screen and meet perfectly in the middle. Any thoughts?

Comment: @RandyBanks Maybe this works:self.postButtonLeadingConstraint.constant = -self.deleteButton.frame.size.width-self.postButtonLeadingConstraint.constant

Comment: @RandyBanks And self. is not needed in Swift.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I imagine this problem must be stemming from somewhere else in my view design that I have not included in my post. I can solve the issue by hardcoding in an extra 30 pixels in the subtraction, but I don't want to leave it like this for obvious reasons

Comment: @RandyBanks It looks like this.

Comment: What was that reference you used to the trailing edge of the screen in your original comment? I'm thinking something along the lines of subtracting half of that value from my post button's leading edge constraint

Answer (score 1):

If you're targeting iOS 9 and higher then I'd suggest using `UIStackView`. This is super easy that way, just a matter of adding and/or removing the button from/to stack view. Here's [little sample](https://github.com/libec/StackOverflow/tree/master/08-StackView) to help you understand.

Comment: I'll add that you don't even necessarily need to remove the button from the stack view. The stack 'monitors' the `hidden` property of the contained views and will adjust the layout correctly simply by setting the button's hidden property to `true`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that although you are hiding the button, it's width remains unchanged. If you use

```
self.deleteButtonWidthConstraint.constant = 0
```

Where `deleteButtonWidthConstraint` is an @IBOutlet hooked up to the delete button's width constraint.